# Why does the Material Design floating label not work for an AJAX loaded Bootstrap modal?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, razor, bootstrap-modal, bootstrap-material-design

I have a pretty typical Boostrap Modal:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Create New Customer</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body mb-1 pb-1 ">
                <form asp-page-handler="CustomerModalPartial"  >
                    <input name="IsValid" type="hidden" value="@ViewData.ModelState.IsValid.ToString()" />
                    <input name="Id" type="hidden" value="@ViewData.Model.Id" />
                    <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label asp-for="Name" class="bmd-label-floating" for="input-name">Company Name</label>
                        <input asp-for="Name" class="form-control" type="text" id="input-name" />
                        <span asp-validation-for="Name" class="text-danger"></span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label asp-for="ContactName" class="bmd-label-floating" for="input-contactName">Customer Name</label>
                        <input asp-for="ContactName" class="form-control" type="text" id="input-contactName" />
                        <span asp-validation-for="ContactName" class="text-danger"></span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label asp-for="ContactEmail" class="bmd-label-floating" for="input-contactEmail">Customer Email</label>
                        <input asp-for="ContactEmail" class="form-control" type="email" id="input-contactEmail" />
                        <span asp-validation-for="ContactEmail" class="text-danger"></span>
                    </div>
                </form>
                <div class="modal-footer mr-0 pr-0">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-save="modal" id="submitButton">Create</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I load the `partial` via

```
 $('button[data-toggle="ajax-modal"]').click(function (event) {
        var url = $(this).data("url");
        $.get(url).done(function(data) {
            placeholderElement.html(data);
            placeholderElement.find(".modal").modal("show");
        });
    });
```

using a button/placeholder setup like so:

```
<div style="position: fixed;bottom: 20px;right: 20px;">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary bmd-btn-fab" data-toggle="ajax-modal" data-url="@Url.Page("Index", "CustomerModalPartial")">+</button>
</div>

<form method="get">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="search" class="bmd-label-floating">Search</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="search" name="currentFilter" value="@Model.CurrentFilter">
        <span class="bmd-help">Search against the customer name, ...</span>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" style="display: none"/>
</form>

<!-- Modal placeholder -->
<div id="modal-placeholder"></div>
```

However, my labels don't float:

[image]

I have confirmed that I do have the MD Bootstrap properly loaded because the page that shows the modal has a floating search:

[image]

Why doesn't my modal have floating labels?

As a side note, I also noticed that I don't get things like checkboxes from the material design bootstrap. I feel like I'm missing something. Thoughts?

Comment: Because there is an input below it without borders? Tested with a clean bootstrap 4 and it shows as it should.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. Updated with the parent page's placeholder.

Comment: Did you ever fix this problem?

Comment: Nope, I did not.